# Structure of set with large pairwise gcd's

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a set of $M$ distinct positive integers, all of size roughly $N$. Assume that the pairwise gcd of elements of $\mathcal{M}$ is large for all pairs. For illustration, let's take $M \approx \sqrt{N}$, and assume that $\gcd(m_1,m_2) \approx N/M \approx \sqrt{N}$ or larger for all pairs $m_1,m_2 \in \mathcal{M}$. (It's not too difficult to see that this is what "large" gcd means here, since it's not possible that all pairwise gcd's are significantly larger than $N/M$.)

It's clear how to construct such a set $\mathcal{M}$: fix one big common factor of order ca. $\sqrt{N}$, and then choose the elements of $\mathcal{M}$ as (maybe pairwise coprime) multiples of this common factor.

But is this the only possibility? In other words: If I have a set of $\sqrt{N}$ numbers, all of order roughly $N$, and if the pairwise gcd is always $\sqrt{N}$ or larger, then does it mean that these numbers all have a large common factor which is **the same** for all numbers? (Or maybe there is a small set of possible large factors, and every element of $\mathcal{M}$ is a multiple of one of these factors.)

I am aware that the question is somewhat imprecise. Also, the numbers and the gcd's and the cardinality of the set don't have to be exactly what is written above, but could be a bit smaller or larger. But the question is: is it generally true that having so many large gcd's requires all numbers to be multiples of a large common factor, or multiples of a small set of possible large common factors, and if yes, then what sort of argument could prove such a structural result? Also, what happens when I don't request *all* pairwise gcd's to be so large, but just a "high" proportion of gcd's?

Comment: You can't have any small differences, second differences, third differences, etc. So yes, that is what they look like: multiples of the same gcd.  For  high proportion, do 3-smooth numbers satisfy? Gerhard "You're Not Just Talking Smooth" Paseman, 2019.05.24.

Comment: Do you have any specific bounds? For example, how small is $m_1$ allowed to be in terms of $N$, or how large is $m_M$ allowed to be?

Comment: I’m gonna be lazy and note the following. Let’s write S instead of \mathcal{M} since I’m on my phone. Let m\in S. There are << N^\eps divisors of m. In particular there are << N^\eps divisors of m that are of size \sqrt{N}. For each such divisor d | m of size \sqrt{N}, let S_d := {n\in S : d | n}. Observe that the union of the S_d is all of S by hypothesis. Observe also that every S_d is of the “trivial” form. Thus there is a decomposition of S into a union of few “trivial” subsets. I hope I get to learn a weighted Erdos-Ko-Rado theorem in the inevitable “correct” answer to this question!

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. @Gerhard: It's a correct observation. However, as I understand this really only applied when ALL $M^2$ pairwise gcd's are that large. If I can only assume that, say, $M^2/10$ pairwise gcd's are that large, then such an argument doesn't really apply anymore, right?

Comment: @user44191: I am thinking of $m_1, ..., m_M$ of being roughly of the same size, so let's say they are all in $[N,2N]$. I didn't mean that they all have to be extremely close to $N$.

Comment: @alpoge: As I understand, this isn't really a decomposition, since the $S_d$ are not dijoint, right? Also, having $N^\varepsilon$ "substructures" is too much for me, I thought it should rather be something like constant or logarithmic or something.

Comment: @KurisutoAsutora I see —- I was just going off your parenthetical that perhaps there is a small set of factors for which every element is a multiple of one of these factors. In any case I certainly agree that the optimal bound should be far better, I just gave a quick answer in case the minimum of d(m) over your set was a good enough bound for you.

Comment: In graph theoretic terms, the argument does apply to the largest clique with common gcd, and as in alpoge's suggestion, it matters how many large cliques make up your set.  I believe thinking about 3-smooth or 5-smooth numbers containing  your set S is a good way to approach this problem.  Gerhard "Maybe Small Divisors Will Coalesce" Paseman, 2019.05.25.